# What's going on with this struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, typedef

I'm really struggling to know what's going on with this `struct` in `C++` :

```
typedef struct nod{
int nr;
nod* next;
}NOD;
```

I know what a `struct` is and what purposes have, but I don't realize why "nod" and "NOD" is duplicate .And what's going on with the nod* inside the structure ?

This code is from chained lists.

if somebody can help me, I would appreciate it !!

Comment: nod and NOD is NOT duplicate. Just so you know, C/C++ is case-sensitive. nod* is pointing to structure itself. Read about self-referential structures.

Comment: `NOD` is a `typedef` (alias) for `struct nod`. In C this can save you from having to type the word `struct` whenever you create instances of the type. C++ doesn't make you do that in the first place, so this sort of construct is usually redundant there.

Comment: NOD is a new type, declared as being `struct nod` - no black magic.

Comment: Relevant: [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/612328/3549027)

Answer (score 2):

`typedef a b` creates an alias so that you can refer to `a` by writing `b`. So `typedef struct nod {...} NOD` allows you to refer to `struct nod` as  `NOD`.

Without the `typedef`, i.e. `struct nod {...};`, you'd have to refer to the struct as `struct nod` in C code, while in C++ you could still refer to it as  simply `nod`.

`nod* next` declares a member variable of the struct. The type of that variable is pointer to a `nod`, and it's name is `next`.

Comment: I am not the down voter, and I cannot see anything you said that is technically wrong.  The only thing I see perhaps is that the wording in the 3rd sentence is a little loose, and may have confused someone away from your intended thought.  I reduced it in my mind to: _typedef struct a{...}A; allows the use of an alias_ ***A*** _in place of ***struct a***, allowing for more readable C code.  This is a C technique as C++ allows  the use of the struct name,_ ***a*** _in this case, without first typedefing it._   +1 in any case, for a complete answer.

Comment: @ryyker Thanks, I modified it, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

NOD and nod are not the same. NOD is a typedef, which basically means "the name of the struct". So you can define an object of it by typing:

```
NOD node;
```

However, `nod*` is different. It is a pointer of type `nod`, which is your struct. This can be used to chain together different struct objects and create a linked list like so:

```
Nod node1;
Nod node2;
Nod node3;

node1->next = node2;
node2->next = node3;
```

Comment: "NOD and nod are not the same." What's the difference? Both are names/identifiers and both name the same type.

Answer (score 0):

This defines a **node** in a linked data structure. Each node contains a pointer to another node (of the same type).

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` define NOD as a synonym for the type `struct node`. So after that you can define a `struct type node` with NOD and NOD works as an allies of `struct node`. Now you can declare a new `struct node` with less verbiage -

```
NOD node1, node2;
```

And the `node*` pointer inside the `NOD` is used to pointing an another `struct node`. Actually this `struct node` data structure is used to represent a node of a linked list.

Comment: The question is about C++, not C.  The "verbiage saved" is just the e in `node`. The keyword `struct` is only needed in the struct definition itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as :

```
typedef struct nod NOD;
struct nod {
  int nr;
  nod* next;
};
```

It is a linked list struct with struct member back referencing (pointing) its own type.

This is an old C convention (to neglect struct keyword) while in C++ the typedef is not quite needed here.